# handlebars.js is not rendering template in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, handlebars.js

I'm working on a simple site using handlebars.js. It works just well in FF, Chrome, IE11 and Mobile Browsers. However, in IE9 the template is not gonna be rendered. Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

here's the site:
http://dev.thomasveit.com/zuzuegler

any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking at your code reveals you use HTML5 tags, such as Footer or even more.
IE9 unfortunately is not able to render HTML5 tags.

There are many ways to fix your problem... best IMO is to try using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Just include it in your html file, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i use https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/ for HTML5 support in IE, that should not be the problem.

Comment: It seems that you have infinite recursion in your code. Check the console and you will notice the SCRIPT28: Out of stack space error

Comment: Thanks @Wexoni! Unfortunately I don't have access to developer tools in IE9 in my working environment... =/ but don't you think other browser would crash too when I have infinite recursion? seems like others have problems too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338114/handlebar-js-memory-leak-in-ie9

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The problem was indeed the html5shim for IE9. I just removed it and now it works fine.